# Stop fixed sidebar at Footer

Tags: jquery

How can I prevent the sidebar from going past the footer using Jquery?

### The sidebar with the script now goes behind the footer.

```js
<script>
  jQuery(function() {
     if ( jQuery(window).width() > 1026) {   
        jQuery('.widgetable').scrollToFixed({marginTop:80,zIndex:9});
     }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I think css would be better to use than jquery

Answer (score 0):

As I can see on the [ScrollToFixed documentation](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed), there is a limit attribute.

```
jQuery(function () {
  if ( jQuery(window).width() > 1026) {   
    jQuery('.widgetable').scrollToFixed({
      marginTop: 80,
      zIndex: 9,
      limit: $('.footer').offset().top,
    });

  }
});
```

Comment: I have tried adding this using Chrome console but it doesnt seem to do the trick, the sidebar still passes the footer.

Comment: @SavenzSavisaarKulbach Does the footer has a class or id name?

Comment: footer is #footer, but i called is #footer in the limit string